# How to get context in flutter Workmanager

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-workmanager

Am trying to implement Workmanager in flutter code and need context inside the function.

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    await AuthController.refreshToken(context);
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

The above code shows error in context and also tried

```
await AuthController.refreshToken(inputData?[context]);
```

This will shows an error --- BackgroundWorker(16318): errorCode: error, errorMessage: Null check operator used on a null value.

Anyone have any idea abuot this?

Comment: why do you need a `BuildContext` in `AuthController`?

Comment: @MohamedMohsin I need to store the token in state.

Comment: have you find out the solution?

Answer (score -3):

In a Flutter application, the `context` object is typically available within the widget tree and is not directly accessible in background tasks like WorkManager. However, you can pass necessary data or dependencies to your background task using the `inputData` parameter.

To pass the context to your `callbackDispatcher` function, you can modify the function signature to accept an additional parameter for the context:

```dart
void callbackDispatcher(BuildContext context) {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    await AuthController.refreshToken(context);
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Then, when you schedule the background task using WorkManager, you can pass the context as input data:

```dart
void scheduleBackgroundTask(BuildContext context) {
  Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
    "myTask",
    "myTaskName",
    inputData: {'context': context.toString()},
  );
}
```

In the above example, the context is converted to a string using `context.toString()` and passed as input data with the key "context".

Finally, within the `refreshToken` method of `AuthController`, you can retrieve the context from the input data:

```dart
class AuthController {
  static Future<void> refreshToken(Map<String, dynamic> inputData) async {
    final String contextString = inputData['context'] as String;
    final BuildContext context = WidgetsBinding.instance!.renderViewElement!.buildContext!;
    // Use the context as needed in the background task
  }
}
```

Note that you need to import `package:flutter/widgets.dart` to access the `BuildContext` class.

By passing the context as input data and retrieving it within the background task, you can work with the context indirectly. However, keep in mind that the context may not provide the same functionality as in the UI context.

Comment: This shows : Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'buildContext'.

Comment: @kapiltk this solution worked for you?

Comment: Not working.. Showing error on .buildContext!;

Comment: Ok bro thanks for the effort

Comment: @kapiltk sorry i misunderstood the question. Actually the approach to accessing the BuildContext within a background task is different from what I mentioned earlier. In a Flutter background task, you won't have direct access to the BuildContext because the background task runs independently of the UI.

Instead of passing the BuildContext directly, you can pass the necessary data or dependencies to the background task using the inputData parameter in the executeTask method.

Comment: Your 8 most recent answers all appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.